# Execute a transition a specific date with NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus

I'm working on a system where the lifetime of a subscription is handle with a state machine and I'm looking at NServiceBus as a replacement for the management of transitions between states.

**Example**

A customer has an active internet subscription and would like to cancel it 3 months in the future.

**Current Solution**

A transition is created in the database e.g.

```
tranistionId: 10000,
subscriptionId: 1337,
transition: "execute-inactivation"
due-date: {current date + 3 months}
```

The table is scanned every 10s to see if there are any new/due transitions.

**NServiceBus**

I think it would be possible to replicate the current solution with:

```
Schedule.Every(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Action(() => 
{ 
    Bus.Send<CheckForDueTransitions>(); 
});
```

But that will not remove the problem with the chattiness against the database.

Another important feature is that's possible to a *abort a queued transition* e.g. cancel the cancellation.

Is there a preferred NServiceBus solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [NServiceBus Sagas](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/860458-sagas-in-nservicebus). You might think of each subscription being its own long running process (Saga instance), and using the Timeout Manager to manage them. You could then use the timeout functionality to cancel your subscriptions automatically, on-demand, or if a users extends their subscription, create a new timeout for that subscription to the new expiry date.

Comment: Sorry for the late confirmation, but I've had to spike the implementation off hours.

Comment: Sagas will work if ConfigureHowToFindSaga is overridden since bad it's not allowed to run transitions concurrently for the same subscription, e.g: you cannot jump to the state "blocked" and "inactive" at the same time.